# Compare between excel and word

Tags: vba

I have problems with compare fields between excel and word. Normally the same strings but not in the same format.

1st Example:

```
 string variable1 : Title_of_book
 string variable2 : <<Title_of_book_>>
```

i would like to have compare of that as true because variable1 IS IN variable2. How to do that?

other example:

```
string variable1 : Date_of_creation_document_2012
string variablw2 : «Date_of_creation_document_20»
```

here 12 was cutted somehow in Word but almost whole text is same and this is for sure that field associated so also should be marked as true in compare.

I tried by but its not working as assumed:

```
If InStr(variable1, variablw2) > 0 Then
```

Comment: It is not clear what your problem is. Consider revising your question? As it is currently written, it is difficult to understand. Maybe you tried to input some markup language that is not allowed, because this does not make sense in English:  *Title of book (but in Word it looks like: <> adress is - (al. Mino 456) (but in Word: adress_is___al_*

Comment: @StackUser, I have similar opinion as David Zemens. Please make your problem more clearer. From what I read you want to compare data between Word and Excel. However is your problem corresponding to method of making 2 strings identical ( underlines and other characters) or is it something else?

Comment: i changed main question please of help

Comment: any feedback on that please?

Comment: What is the rule to convert variable1 to variable2?  In first example, "<<" is added at head and  and "_>> is added to tail. In the other hand, in second example,  "<<" is added at head and  and ">> is added to tail.

Answer (score 0):

INSTR function arguments sorting is as follows:

INSTR(Start,Within,What,SearchType)

You must change your line to this ( Change Strings Order ) :

InStr(1, variablw2 , variable1 , vbTextCompare)

Good Luck